# How can I fund a wallet on dev.stellarx?

Tags: new-developer

Can someone tell me how I fund a wallet on dev.stellarx.com?
Below is what I have tried unsuccessfully.

I have created an account on dev.stellarx.com.

Payment Address - `john_whitton*stellarx.com`

Public Key - `GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD`

I then wanted to fund the wallet with some XLM so I went to https://www.stellar.org/laboratory and used the friendbot
https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test

Now my account has a balance when I look via the lab (see below) but there is no balance shown on dev.stellarx.com

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD"
    },
    "transactions": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/transactions{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "operations": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/operations{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "payments": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/payments{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "effects": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/effects{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "offers": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/offers{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "trades": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/trades{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "data": {
      "href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD/data/{key}",
      "templated": true
    }
  },
  "id": "GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD",
  "paging_token": "",
  "account_id": "GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD",
  "sequence": "4847093931835392",
  "subentry_count": 0,
  "thresholds": {
    "low_threshold": 0,
    "med_threshold": 0,
    "high_threshold": 0
  },
  "flags": {
    "auth_required": false,
    "auth_revocable": false,
    "auth_immutable": false
  },
  "balances": [
    {
      "balance": "10000.0000000",
      "buying_liabilities": "0.0000000",
      "selling_liabilities": "0.0000000",
      "asset_type": "native"
    }
  ],
  "signers": [
    {
      "public_key": "GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD",
      "weight": 1,
      "key": "GAP7AWUT7K47U2DI67ZXY56JPK6CGODXJOW3ZVOLVMHLUKGORO24ZURD",
      "type": "ed25519_public_key"
    }
  ],
  "data": {}
}
```

Comment: is *dev*.stellarx.com specifically for testnet?